# Pausing and resuming option in azure blob upload using javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-blob-storage, resumablejs

How to pause the on progress upload of browser files to azure storage account and resume when required using azure storage blob javascript(v12) library file? 
I have tried pausing the uploading process using resumable.js library function
r.pause();
But it is not pausing the uploading process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage JS SDK doesn't support pause and resume naturally.

But if you are using methods like uploadFromStream() in Node.js, you can pause the Node.js Readable stream and resume the stream later.

For browser method like uploadFromBrowserData() which accepts File or Blob type. You can create a customized PauseResume policy and injects into pipeline. The policy can simply hold outgoing requests until resume.

Refer to this simple about how to create a customized policy.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/javascript/customizedClientHeaders.js