# Pause and resume functionality for current uploading process to Azure block block storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am implementing functionality to upload large files (upto 10gb in azure block blob storage) via breaking them into small blocks and then committing them through commitblicklist .I have achieved this functionality in front end( article which i took for my reference is:https://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/) but now **how to implement functionality of pause and resume of currently uploading file** . I couldn't find any reference to that function in any website/article. Please if anyone has any leads into it let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540507/pausing-and-resuming-option-in-azure-blob-upload-using-javascript) if you want to stop and resume the upload of the blob.

If you are using  `uploadFromBrowserData()` it would require
customized Pause Resume policy .
Refer the following [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/v12/javascript/customizedClientHeaders.js) .